# Можно ли передать в after_destroy_commit данные удаляемой строки?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В модели `User` есть строка:

```
after_create_commit { UserAfterCreateCommitJob.perform_later(self) }
```

С ней все понятно. Она работает - в `UserAfterCreateCommitJob` создаю метод `perform`, в нем принимаю на вход `data` и с этим работаю. Все окей.

Но также в этой модели есть строка:

```
after_destroy_commit { UserAfterDestroyCommitJob.perform_later(self) }
```

Вот с ней-то и проблема. Подозреваю, что в нее просто-напросто не передаются данные удаляемой строки (что мне необходимо).

Я прав? И если да, то как быть? Мне после удаления (коммита) необходимо кое-что проделать с удаленными данными.

Answer (score 0):

Помните, каким образом ActiveJob передаёт объекты моделей в объекты задач?
Ну да неважно, я напомню. С помощью [Global ID](https://github.com/rails/globalid), который в случае модели состоит из названия класса и `id` (и внутреннего URL-подобного синтаксиса, что сейчас неважно).

У этого подхода есть две особенности.

- Задача отработает именно на свежей версии объекта, на момент запуска задачи, а не добавления её в очередь.
- Задача может отработать не так, как задумано, если между назначением и запуском задачи объект по ссылке изменился.

Окей, на самом деле это одна и та же особенность под разными углами.

**Передаётся не сам объект, а лишь способ его найти.**

Передавать объект таким способом *после удалившей его транзакции* бессмысленно.

---

Хотите передавать данные и хотите, чтобы они обязательно дошли в неизменном виде, что бы ни произошло? Так передавайте данные. Скажем, не сам объект модели, а [хэшмап его полей, `.attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes). И перед этим неплохо бы ещё выкинуть лишнее оттуда [с помощью `.slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) (или `.except`). А то и вовсе только те значения, что вам реально нужны из модели, *позиционными аргументами*.

А иначе вам лучше бы подождать с удалением. Например, производить его не при обслуживании HTTP-запроса от пользователя, а уже внутри задачи, сообщив, что удаление вот-вот случится, но возможно не прямо сейчас. При этом можно обозначить тот факт, что объект ожидает удаления "с уборкой" каким-нибудь флагом. А то и вообще можно перемещать всю строку в другую таблицу перед удалением.